# ASP.NET MVC Retrieve data with certain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, object, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using a scaffold-ed index function to get all the data from the database.

```
// Scaffold-ed index():
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Objects.ToList());
}

// Database tables:
[ObjectID] [Name]
1          Tree
2          Plant
3          Flower
4          Tree
```

Instead of all the objects, I only what the objects with a certain name (for example: tree). What is the best solution for this and should this be done with methods like `db.Objects.Find()`, `Where()`,.. or with a custom query?

Comment: Your question is unclear, and it looks more Linq and/or ORM related rather than an MVC question.

Comment: You can do that with LINQ, if you have a more complex query you can use a SP for that. Please, be more specific

Comment: Do a google search for LINQ tutorial

Comment: It is a simple query, so can you give an example how to do this with LINQ?

Comment: `db.Objects.Where(w=> w.Name=="SomeName").ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is good for this the code needed would be

```
db.Objects.Where(o => o.Name == "Tree").ToList();
```